# How to send data from Firebase Cloud Messaging dashboard without receiving any notification?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send custom data through Additional Options fields using Firebase Cloud Messaging dashboard to my Android client. Then using those data I'll create a custom notification layout and notify my client manually.

[image: example]

I tried doing that using my custom notification functions. Sometimes it works. But sometimes it shows firebase notification...

[image]

So is there any ways to disable that Firebase one and show a new one after configuring manually on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it,

Adding,

```
android:exported="false"
```

to my service data in AndroidManifest file worked for me.

```
        <service
            android:name=".XXXXXXXCloudMessagingSerivce"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send **Data messages** in order to show custom notification. Have a look at [Message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)